# Input range with contrast filter

Tags: jquery, css, input, range

I tried to create `input ranger` for apply contrast filter in div:

https://jsfiddle.net/ckekj8dn/

But it not working

Thanks for any help

```js
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
  $('#mydiv').css('contrast', $(this).val() + "%");
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200/");
  background-size: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>

Contrast
<input id="contrast" type="range" value="opacity_fundo" max="1" min="0" step="0.01" />
<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `contrast` property in CSS. You're probably looking for the [CSS3 `filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Since this property [isn't supported in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), you will need to add some prefixed properties for additional browser support. I added the `-webkit` prefix so that it works in Chrome/Safari. See [this chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) for browser support.

According to MDN documentation for the [`filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), you can pass a percentage or a decimal. The `input` element returns a decimal, which means that you could simply use a decimal, or you could multiply the decimal by 100 and round it (i.e., `Math.round(this.value * 100)`).

> Except where noted, the functions that take a value expressed with a percent sign (as in 34%) also accept the value expressed as decimal (as in 0.34).

As a side note, I also set the value of the range `input` element to `1` by default (since the contrast of the image is 1).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ysjvep6v/)

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
  $('#mydiv').css({
    '-webkit-filter': 'contrast(' + this.value + ')',
    'filter': 'contrast(' + this.value + ')'
  });
});
```

It's also pretty simple to do this without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3cLe6mnt/)

```
document.getElementById('contrast').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');

  element.style.webkitFilter = 'contrast(' + this.value + ')';
  element.style.filter = 'contrast(' + this.value + ')';
});
```

```js
document.getElementById('contrast').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
      
  element.style.webkitFilter = 'contrast(' + this.value + ')';
  element.style.filter = 'contrast(' + this.value + ')';
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://www.lorempixel.com/200/200/");
  background-size: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<label>Contrast:
  <input id="contrast" type="range" value="1" max="1" min="0" step="0.01" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. I also thank your great explanation

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jy640ng1/2/ I do not know why the contrast value is lost when using the blur after

Comment: @Zeli It's not working because you're overriding the `filter` property each time. You need to stack the values like `'filter': 'blur(' + blur + 'px) contrast(' + contrast + ')'` see this [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/zpqkyytp/) - https://jsfiddle.net/zpqkyytp/

Comment: The html2Canvas does not recognize the filters when I download the image appears without filters. You already know any solution for this? My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684048/html2canvas-not-working-for-webkit-filter-suggestions-for-similar

Answer (score 2):

My version: https://jsfiddle.net/ckekj8dn/2/

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
    var contrast = $(this).val();
    $('#mydiv').css({
        'filter': 'contrast(' + contrast + ')',
      '-webkit-filter': 'contrast(' + contrast + ')'
    });
});
```

You need -webkit-filter for Chrome, Safari.

Check this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Answer (score 1):

See https://jsfiddle.net/unuwg0q6/1/

```
$('#contrast').on('input', function() {
    $('#mydiv').css('filter', 'contrast(' + $(this).val()  + ")");
});
```

You need to use `filter` css to change the contrast.