# Html2Canvas Not working for webkit-filter - Suggestions for similar

Tags: image, download, html2canvas, css-filters

Html2Canvas works perfectly to make div content download, but when the div contains css filters the html2Canvas not apply the filters in the generated image.

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/246

Would welcome suggestions for something similar to Html2Canvas to download (image) the contents of a div

Thanks for any help

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` property is not supported by html2canvas. http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/features#unsupported-css-properties

Comment: Rather than pointing out what *can't* be done, answers are generally better received when they provide an option for *how to do* what the OP is asking about.